# Add Event Method Is Adding Cell To Top, Not Bottom

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have the following method which is adding a cell to a tableview.  I want the added cell to be at the bottom, however right now it is adding it at the top.  Any suggestions?

addEvent method:

```
-(void)addEvent
{    
    Routine *routine = (Routine *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Routine" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    routine.name=entered;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        // Handle the error.
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", error);

    [eventsArray insertObject:routine atIndex:0];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

    [self.routineTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    [self.routineTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
     }
```

ViewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    if (managedObjectContext == nil) 
    { 
        managedObjectContext = [(CurlAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]; 
    }

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Routine" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
    if (mutableFetchResults == nil) {
        // Handle the error.
    }
    [self setEventsArray:mutableFetchResults];
    [mutableFetchResults release];
    [request release];

    UIBarButtonItem * addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(showPrompt)];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:addButton];
    [addButton release];

    UIBarButtonItem *editButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Edit" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(toggleEdit)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButton;
    [editButton release];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`0` is the first index. As a rule (there are likely to be a few exceptions somewhere in the world) things that are to do with indexes, start at 0. Whereas things like `count` start at 1.

So if you have an array with 1 object in it, the array's count will be `1`, and the object will be at index `0`.

When you are using 0, for you `indexPath`'s row and section your telling it to put it at the top of the tableview.

So make you last 4 lines of code something like this:

```
[eventsArray addObject:routine];

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

[self.routineTableView reloadData];

NSInteger lastSection = [self.routineTableView numberOfSections] -1;

[self.routineTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.routineTableView numberOfRowsInSection:lastSection]-1 inSection:lastSection] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
```

Comment: Yes I understand that, I tried doing `[self.routineTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[eventArray count] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];` but I get an error with that. Any other ideas?

Comment: Same reason, the count will be 1 bigger than the index. As the count starts on 1, but the index starts at 0. You need to do `[self.routineTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[eventArray count]-1 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];`

Comment: Personally I'd just use reloadData, as I have in my answer

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I tried implementing that code but can't get `[self.routineTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.routineTableView numberOfCellsInSection:lastSection]-1 inSection:lastSection] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];` to work.  I get an error before compiling: semantic issue and balling out of control, etc.

Comment: `Arithmetic on pointer to interface id, which is not a constant size in non-fragile ABI`

Comment: Sorry, I had missed out an `s` on the lastSection line. The code should work now.

Comment: I have all the `lastSection` integer syntax typed ok, but still getting that antithetic error.

Comment: I got it working, its supposed to be`numberOfRowsInSection`, not `numberOfCellsInSection`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably use [eventsArray addObject:] instead of insertObject:atIndex:

Also, you should be able to use [self.routineTableView reloadData]; rather than inserting rows manually -- assuming you've set up the table view controller in a normal way.

Comment: Thanks, picciano.  Could you expand on this?  Is there a better way to update the table using reloadData rather than the way I am doing it?

Answer (score 0):

The specific answer to your question is that your table has an array as a datasource and you are adding a new item at the beginning of the array. Therefore, when the table is reloaded, the new cell is at the top.

For a deeper understanding, I recommend you understand the following topics at minimum:

1. common data types used as data sources with tables (arrays and dictionaries mainly)
2. how table views work (e.g. what is tableView.dataSource and tableView.delegate)
3. methods of reloading the table when the dataSource changes (what you did is ok but not always what you'll want)

Comment: Thanks Xjones, could you please tell me about reloading the table and how I should do it as apposed to what I did? Thanks.

Comment: The most common way is what @picciano recommended. Use `[tableView reloadData]`. That will load the whole table. The other methods for inserting, deleting, and loading specific sections and rows are documented in the UITableView docs. They are most commonly used when you want a user interaction to modify the data source and animate a change to the table.

Comment: Something else for you to look into. I see you are using Core Data to store your `routine` data. Looks like you are also then maintaining a separate array `eventsArray` that contain your `routine` instances. There are a few problems with that. You should use an NSFetchedResultsController as your data source. Again, the Apple docs can get you going and if you have specific questions search and/or ask here. Good luck!

Comment: I didn't post the whole code but in my ViewDidLoad, I have a fetch request and `[self setEventsArray:mutableFetchResults];`.  Isn't this the correct way of doing it?  Ill add the code to my original question.

Comment: You can use a fetch request but maintaining the events array outside of the database is what will get you into trouble. Especially if your app ever modifies data from multiple controllers/threads. An NSFetchedResultsController uses a fetch request but is explicitly designed to drive table views and give its delegate appropriate notifications based on data model changes to update the table appropriately. Read the docs and you'll understand. I wouldn't add it to this question, it's not really relevant here.

Comment: Wow the NSFetchedResultsController sounds good in my case.  I'll make a separate question for this matter and will look over the apple doc as well.  Thanks.